# How to eliminate back bar button animation in a UISplitViewController app?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

In a non-IUSplitViewController app, I am able to suppress the default back bar animation by adding this to my UIApplicationDelegate class header:

```
@interface MyNavigationBar : UINavigationBar { } @end
@interface MyNavigationController : UINavigationController { } @end
```

along with this in the corresponding .m:

```
@implementation MyNavigationController
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    return( [super popViewControllerAnimated:NO] );
}
@end

@implementation MyNavigationBar
- (UINavigationItem *)popNavigationItemAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    return( [super popNavigationItemAnimated:NO] );
}
@end
```

Of course I also assigned the Navigation Controller and Navigation Bar objects in MainWindow.xib to MyNavigationController and MyNavigationBar respectively in Interface Builder.

This works like a charm in a standard application.

My problem is achieving the same thing in a UISplitViewController app.

Specifically, I cannot figure out how to override the default behavior of UINavigationBar in that case in order to suppress animation of the navigation bar when a view controller is popped via the back bar button.

I *can* override the behavior of UINavigationController by doing this whenever I instantiate a UIViewController as the root of the UISplitViewController right pane:

```
[split is a pointer to my UISplitViewController]

MyNavigationController *nc = (MyNavigationController *) [split.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
nc = [[[MyNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:someController] autorelease];
split.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [split.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0], nc, nil];
split.delegate = someController;
```

To recap, when I hit the back bar button in my UISplitViewController app, the content area of the active view controller does not animate when popped via the back bar button, but the navigation bar does animate, which looks dopey.

I found the solution for the standard application case in this forum, but saw no mention of a UISplitViewController solution.

I tried overriding initWithCoder in MyNavigationController to assign an instance of MyNavigationBar to the navigationBar attribute, but it wouldn't let me since it is read-only.

Stumped.